# django admin, how to check model instance belong to owner before deleting?

Tags: django, django-admin

I tried overwriting def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):, but obj is not passed when deleting a record in Django Admin.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: It certainly is passed when deleting a record. Please show the code you've used, in context, and show how you've determined that it is not being passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**model**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Item(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    info = models.TextField()
```

**view**

```
obj = Item.objects.get(id=1)
if obj.owner == request.user:
    obj.delete()
```

In order to do this within Django Admin you need to override the `delete_model` method in `admin.py` file. Use the following code for the model above to make sure the users only delete their own content, and no one else's.

**admin.py**

```
class ItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def delete_model(self, request, obj):
        if obj.owner == request.user:
            obj.delete()
        return

admin.site.register(Item, ItemAdmin)
```

Now try to create two objects in the model from the admin page and use two separate users as the owner. You will be able to delete only your content, but not others. I checked the code. This works for me.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am using the admin, not my own view.

Comment: There is a very complicated solution in Pro Django book. And it's for older Django versions. Because you have to get the request in models file to compare the current owner with the current user. And it is also not advised to bring request to models. So there is a complication. I'll get back to you if I have something. Thanks.

Comment: @smallbee Please check my updated answer. This will surely work. Please upvote and accept the answer if this has helped you.